# Suggested Edits reveal spoilers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, spoilers

I was going through suggested edits, and received an unwanted dose of spoil:

> [Image contains D3 spoiler!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhVj6.png)

Perhaps the text in the spoiler block that has been changed could be made the same colour as its background (red/green) so that it's invisible until rolled over, the same as the rest of the spoiler block?

Comment: [Rub some bacon on it.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4781882#4781882)

Comment: I like how you are sharing the pain by directly posting the image. :P

Comment: @FAE I put it in a spoiler block!

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, what are you doing *editing* content if you don't already know the content? If anything, the edit page shouldn't hide spoilers at all. This also applies to approving suggested edits.

Comment: This is a suggested edit from `/tools`. I click there and it comes up, I have no idea what's going to be there. I'm saying that spoiler diffs should only be visible on rollover. Obviously if you don't want to be spoiled, you leave it to someone else to make the decision.

Comment: @fredley Ah, that makes quite a lot more sense then. I am still going to leave this up though because I still think spoilers shouldn't hide when editing.